# Как выложить приложение в app store

Tags: ios, xcode

Помогите, пожалуйста! Пытаюсь выложить приложение в app store, ничего не выходит. Остановился на архивации. В App loader закидываю архив и выдает ERROR ITMS-90017: "This bundle is invalid. ..., а если через Product-archive еще больше всякого. Что делать? Перелазил весь инет, просмотрел видео там все просто.

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AutoSimAlarm-ckmgeyfjgjfhxmbzniyhiedexnel/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AutoSimAlarm/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/AutoSimAlarm.build/Release-iphoneos/AutoSimAlarm.build/Objects-normal/armv7/AutoSimAlarm (No such file or directory)

(null): error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AutoSimAlarm-ckmgeyfjgjfhxmbzniyhiedexnel/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AutoSimAlarm/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/AutoSimAlarm.app/AutoSimAlarm": No such file or directory

Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip failed with exit code 1

Что то многовато!!!

Comment: покажите, что product-archive вам выдает

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Линкер, вызванный `clang`, упал по сегфолту? Вот это да.

Comment: Боюсь, что это невозможно повторить. Могу лишь посоветовать экспортировать профиль разработчика в xcode, импортировать его на другой мак и попробовать собрать приложение там. Не понятно проблема в приложении или в самом xcode.

Comment: сотрите derived data и сделайте clean

Comment: а если просто собирать и запускать, то все работает?

Comment: Просто Product/build, simulator и на устройстве работает.

Comment: С архивом разобрался, просто обновил Xcode до 7.3.1. Теперь не грузит в itunesconnect файл ipa создан. Выдает:                                 ERROR ITMS-90167: "No .app bundles found in the package". Подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

Архив должен быть верно подписан, содержать корректный dsym файл и т.п. Сложно что-то рекомендовать не имея общей картины. В целом всё сводится к нескольким шагам:

В настройках проекта

1) Provisioning Profile > Release
Выбираете профайл дистрибуции созданный на developer.apple.com на вкладке iOS Provisioning Profiles (Distribution) под Ваше приложение

2) Code Signing Identity > Release > Any IOS SDK
Выбираете профиль разработчика, он подтягивается как правило с предыдущего шага.

3) Архивируете (Product/Archive)

4) Сохраняете в открывшемся окне (export > save for ios app store deployment)

Полученный архив можно загружать через App loader

Comment: Прошелся заново по вашему списку. Ошибки добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я не помню, какие у меня ошибки были - не сохранил скриншоты, но тоже как-то в апреле 2020 была проблема - собрать одно приложение.
На этапе создания архива процесс валился.

Из-за чего это произошло: у меня не удалялись некоторые архивы, и я замочил вручную через проводник их папки. И, похоже, что удалил что-то лишнее...
Отправил исходники товарищу - у него все собралось.
Переустановка xCode не помогла :(
Самое интересное, что другие приложения собирались у меня без ошибок.

Помогло следующее: переименовал папку с исходниками проекта и заново открыл. Архив успешно был создан.